# How to create Telugu language ( UTF ) json API in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Mysql database contains data in tealugu language (UTF). The php script is returning json in this format.But is not understandable.

[{"P_Title":"\u0c26\u0c4d\u0c2b\u0c4d\u0c26\u0c4d\u0c38\u0c35\u0c4d\u0c35\u0c4d"}]

Please provide a php script that returns Telugu(UTF) json from mysql database.

Comment: "But is not understandable" --- what does it mean? The json is perfectly valid and contains exactly what you need.

Comment: I want response in Json Format not to display in webpage(HTML) directly.Response has to be parsed and displayed.

Comment: That's correct: JSON must be parsed before it's used. And your current JSON is correct.

Answer (score 0):

First set appropriate meta tags for your site:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
// $json is your json object
$array = json_decode($json, true);
echo htmlentities($array[0]['P_Title'], NULL, 'UTF-8');
```

Output:

```
ద్ఫ్ద్సవ్వ్
```